# Exclude null objects from JSON array with Gson

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I'm using Gson to parse my REST API calls to Java objects.

I want to filter out null objects in an array, e.g.

```
{
  list: [
    {"key":"value1"},
    null,
    {"key":"value2"}
  ]
}
```

should result in a `List<SomeObject>` with 2 items.

How can you do this with Gson?

Comment: Added an answer which may cover your needs :) let me know if you need additional support.

Comment: @Quentin did you get answer of this question i also have same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Answer: The Custom Serializer**

You can add a custom serializer for `List.class` which would look like:

```
package com.dominikangerer.q27637811;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class RemoveNullListSerializer<T> implements JsonSerializer<List<T>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<T> src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {

        // remove all null values
        src.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

        // create json Result
        JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
        for(T item : src){
            result.add(context.serialize(item));
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

This will remove the `null` values from the list using `Collections.singleton(null)` and `removeAll()`.

**Register your Custom Serializer**

Now all you have to do is register it to your Gson instance like:

```
g = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new RemoveNullListSerializer()).create();
```

---

## **Downloadable & executable Example**

You can find this answer and the exact example in my github stackoverflow answers repo:

[Gson CustomSerializer to remove Null from List by DominikAngerer](https://github.com/DominikAngerer/StackoverflowJavaAnswers/tree/master/src/main/java/com/dominikangerer/q27637811)

---

## **See also**

- [Gson User Guide - Custom serializers and deserializers](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ)

Comment: is this also possible in the other direction? deserialization?

Comment: Sure - you can write your own deserializer for that. `@Override
   public List<T> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
     ...
   }`

Comment: @DominikAngerer During de-serialization if the structure of the json is not know how would you remove all the null's from the given json element?

Comment: @striker good question - I will think about a solution and come back to this :)

Comment: @DominikAngerer I found a solution for this, the trick would be to register a derserializer for the type List and have a deserializer to remove all the JSON Null, I posted in the answers section, so it may help others as well

Comment: @DominikAngerer plz take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632125/org-json-jsonobject1-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-error-while-parsing-json/40633046#40633046

Comment: for null removing null or Empty Value's field? any soulution ? if value is empty like {name:{x="",y="12",z=""}}

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the null values from a list regardless of their structure, first we need to register a de-serializer with the gson like this

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new RemoveNullListDeserializer()).create();
```

Then the custom de-serializer would remove the null like this

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Deserializer that helps remove all <code>null</code> values form the <code>JsonArray</code> .
 */
public class RemoveNullListDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<List<T>>
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        for(final JsonElement jsonElement : json.getAsJsonArray())
        {
            if(jsonElement.isJsonNull())
            {
                continue;
            }
            jsonArray.add(jsonElement);
        }

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        List<?> list = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, typeOfT);
        return (List<T>) list;
    }
}
```

Hope this help others, who want to remove null values from a json array, regardless of the incoming json structure

Answer (score 0):

My answer maybe late but I expect it works. This question can be solved by removing all the null elements in the Java object when deserialize the json string. So first, we define the custom **JsonDeserializer** for type **List**

```java
public class RemoveNullListDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {
    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

And then, remove all null elements in the JsonElement. Here we use recursive to handle these potential null elements.

```java
    private void removeNullEleInArray(JsonElement json) {
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JsonElement ele = jsonArray.get(i);
                if (ele.isJsonNull()) {
                    jsonArray.remove(i);
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                removeNullEleInArray(ele);
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
                JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get(key);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonArray() || jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    removeNullEleInArray(jsonElement);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

It's worth noting that only remove the null elements in top class is not enough.

And next step, transfer this method when deserialize.

```java
public class RemoveNullListDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {
    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        removeNullEleInArray(json)
        return Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT)
    }
}
```

Finally, register the adapter for creating your Gson:

```java
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new RemoveNullListDeserializer())
                .create();
```

Just Over！