# org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject error while parsing json string

Tags: android, json, android-json

For parsing json i use JSONArray and JsonObject:

```
 protected void parseJson()
    {
        JSONObject object=null;
        try {

            object=new JSONObject(json);
            myArray=object.getJSONArray(MY_ARRAY);
            Log.e("Array Length",""+myArray.length());
            key_id=new String[myArray.length()];
            key_name=new String[myArray.length()];

            for (int i=0;i<=myArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject fetchObject=myArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    key_id[i] = fetchObject.getString(KEY_ID);
                    key_name[i] = fetchObject.getString(KEY_NAME);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

JSON DATA:

```
 {
        "data": [{
            "key": 1,
            "myval": "hello"
        }, {
            "key": 1,
            "myval": "hello"
        }, {
            "key": 1,
            "myval": "hello"
        }, null, {
            "key": 1,
            "myval": "hello"
        }, {
            "key": 1,
            "myval": "hello"
        }]
    }
```

My problem is that when fetchObject get the null object it give me `org.json.JSONObject$1` cannot be converted to JSONObject in try catch .
Please help me how can i solve this.....Thanks for reading....

Comment: Why are you working so hard on parsing code instead of using a json parsing library like GSON is Jackson ?

Comment: your json structure is saying something else and your code is doing something else , it's looks suspicious

Comment: Why the api guy send you a null??? you can ask if key and myval is blank, they can give blank string like {
  "key": 1,
  "myval": ""
 }  Then your problem will be solved

Comment: Hello Manish - I'll come to you asap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading JsonArray and JsonObject doc i understand how to sort out this problem.

```
protected void parseJson()
    {
        JSONObject object=null;
        try {

            object=new JSONObject(json);
            myArray=object.getJSONArray(MY_ARRAY);
            Log.e("Array Length",""+myArray.length());
            key_id=new String[myArray.length()];
            key_name=new String[myArray.length()];

            for (int i=0;i<=myArray.length();i++)
            {

                JSONObject fetchObject=myArray.optJSONObject(i);

                    if(fetchObject==null)
                   {
                     //do nothing
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    key_id[i] = fetchObject.getString(KEY_ID);
                    key_name[i] = fetchObject.getString(KEY_NAME);

                   }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually it's exactly what nzala told you to try :) :+1: for you nzala

Answer (score 3):

```
if(obj.length() == 0)
```

is what I would do.

```
JSONObject fetchObject;

if(flowerArray.getJSONObject(i).length() !=0)
```

/

```
fetchObject = flowerArray.getJSONObject(i)
    if(fetchObject== null)
```